# Remote port forwarding through ssh stopped working on windows server 2019 after update

Tags: windows, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, windows-server-2019

Before the recent update the following command worked correctly and opened a ssh tunnel:

```
ssh -R "remote-port:localhost:local-port" remote-ip
```

which I could test by running locally

```
ncat -l 127.0.0.1 local-port
```

and on the remote

```
ncat 127.0.0.1 remote-port
```

However, after an update it stopped working!

Answer (score 0):

After running ssh with -v flag I've noticed that it tries to use ipv6 localhost. I've changed my ssh command to:

```
ssh -R "remote-port:127.0.0.1:local-port" remote-ip
```

and it worked!

Not sure what the windows update changed... but I've found a workaround.